# Get key and value from a JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to get key and value from a JSON data.

```
$.get(url, function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    if (data.Body != null) {
        console.log(data.Body);
    }
});
```

This are my logs:

```
{
    $id: "1", 
    Exceptions: null, 
    ContentType: null, 
    Body: '{text: "Hello World!"}',     
    Version: 0
}

'{text: "Hello World!"}'
```

Now I want to get the key and value from the second (`data.Body`) and after append to a div but i don't manage to get those. I've tried Object.Keys, but does not work. 
Please help me with an answer.
Thanks!

Comment: You would need to dissect the string contained in the `Body` property. You cannot parse it as JSON (before anyone suggests it) as it's not in the correct format. 2 options really, 1. Change the format of the string in `Body` to be valid JSON. 2. Return the Body value as a child object, without having to mess around parsing JSON again. The latter is preferable, IMO.

Comment: Ok, so the format should be "text":"Hello world!" ?

Comment: That's right, eg. `Body: '{"text": "Hello World!"}',`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try like below**

```
 if (data.Body != null) {

    $.each( data.Body, function( key, value ) {
      console.log( key + ": " + value );
    });
}else{
      console.log('data field emplty');
}
```

it will help u.. as u like to show output

Comment: `if (data.Body != null) {
                    console.log(data.Body);
                    var obj = $.parseJSON(data.Body);
                    $.each(obj, function (key, value) {
                        console.log(key + ":" + value);
                    });
                }`
I did something like this and it works. Thanks !

Comment: yes.. that one also correct.. its up2u how u use that jquery api

Comment: its means ur data is not in json,, thats why u need to use $.parseJSONE functions

Answer (score 0):

Hi your body property contains string value you need to convert it to JSON.

try following code

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( data.Body ); 
alert( obj.text );
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it in earlier app:

```
function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (i, state) {
                $("#BoardIDFK").append('<option value="'
                    + state.Value + '">'
                    + state.Text + '</option>');
            });
        },
```